# iOS - Using addSubView on a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, ios-4.2, cakeyframeanimation

I am trying to use this bit of code:

```
[[myUIView layer] addSublayer: layer];
[myScrollView addSubview:myUIView];
[layer addAnimation:[self imagesAnimation] forKey:@"images"];
```

What I am doing to do is taking a layer that will later get a CAKeyFrameAnimate and placing that layer inside a UIView so I can use the standard view function:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return myUIView;
}
```

But I digress... Then placing the UIView & layer inside of a UIScrollView so I get all of that good UIScrollView functionality.

At least this is how I believe it to work atm.

Hoping for some help currently it just shows a white screen but when I replace the first to lines with:

```
[[myScrollView layer] addSublayer: layer];
```

I get an animation that plays but now zooming goodness.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: In summary what I am trying to do is is have a CAKeyFrameAination inside of a layer inside of a UIView inside of a UIScrollView. The reason for this packing is because I need an Animation that can stop start and zoom in. the First three lines of code produce a blank white screen but when I replace them with the last bit where I'm putting the layer on myScrollView it plays but as expected I get no zooming as**

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

**is expecting an UIView and doesn't work if I tell it to expect a layer.
Hope this is clearer.**

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is clear. Can you reword your question in greater detail?

Comment: Is it just a typo on the question that you use myUIView on the first line and myView on the second, or is that your problem?

Comment: Typo unfortunately... I wish that was the problem. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was adding the UIView in via code but apparently I needed to add it in via the IB and link it up to the code.